# How to Block USB storage devices in MAC OS c/c++

Tags: c++, c, unix, locking, usb

I want to restrict access to the USB storage devices. Either Just block or give read Only access to everyone.

Only calling process can access that devices No one else.

For Windows I have used **CreateFile**() and **DeviceIoControl**() to lock the Volume.

For Unix : To Make read only I can use **diskUtil** but **I want it through program.**

I don't want to use any registry kind of.

So any idea/solutions in c/c++?

platform : MAC OS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chmod()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) to change permissions on the device or/and mount point(-s). You don't even need a program - that can be achieved via **udev** rules. However, I doubt that you can prevent root or sudo users from overriding permissions and accessing devices.

What is the reason behind restricting access to USB storage devices?

Comment: How to disable USB device using udev is in https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2018/06/25/how-to-disable-usb-device/ (the `ATTR{authorized}="0"` in the udev rules file , `/etc/udev/rules.d/01-disable-samsung.rules` in this example)

Comment: @PooSH MAC OS does not support file permission on FAT32 or NTFS. so I have tried **chmod** but No success. To make read Only I can use diskUtility but I need it by program.

Comment: @ralfhtp we can do this way but **root user can modify this rules**. I want only the calling process can access the USB device no ANY OTHERS.

Comment: root user is God in Unix. You cannot limit the root's privileges. If you don't want users to do something - don't give them the root access.

Comment: @PooSH I know but I did it in Windows by **volume locking** so that No one can access even admin system no one.For end point protection only current process can access No one else. or **I want equivalent code** . **Link** for code : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60146126/createfile-and-deviceiocontrol-equivalent-for-volume-devices-in-unix-linux

Comment: @JAYprakash I understand your concerns but Windows Administrator is vastly different from Unix root. Historically, Windows didn't support multi-user mode. When user permissions were finally added, many legacy win32 applications couldn't run normally without admin rights because they were used to the full access to the system. Twenty years later, the majority of Windows users (people) still have admin rights by default. Therefore, extra security features are used to prevent even admins from accessing some features. Unix was initially designed to be a multi-user system.

Comment: I must confess that I'm not an expert in MAC OS. My talk is related mostly to Linux/Unix. Maybe MAC OS has some extra security policies built into the kernel to help you out with the problem.

Comment: @PooSH Did you see the link which I used for windows. Can be equivalent code for Mac OS?

Comment: @PooSH I think **udev** is not for MAC OS btw.

Comment: @JAYprakash to avoid further confusion, please replaces "platform: UNIX" with "MAC OS". Darwin (MAC OS) is not UNIX. It is a UNIX-like, POSIX-compatible OS.

Comment: @PooSH ok Sure. and Thanks for it.

Comment: @PooSH Please have a look on the link in which the code I have used for Windows. Can you please tell equivalent for MAC OS.?